# How do I get a user inputted variable into a sentence?

Tags: python, string-formatting

I need to insert `firstnoun` into the sentence "The [firstnoun] went to the lake.", where `firstnoun` is user inputted.

This is sort of what I have so far:

```
firstnoun = input("Enter your first noun here: ")
```

I need it to print:

> The [firstnoun] went to the lake.

How do I do this? I tried doing

```
print("The" (print(firstnoun)) "went to the lake.")
```

and variations thereof, but none of that is working. I hope the question is clear enough.

Comment: Have you learned about string concatenation yet?  `print('The '+firstnoun+' went to the lake.')` should do it. Note the "+".  Also, in your question, please format your code lines into code blocks to make them easier to read ... you can highlight the line then click the "{}" button.

Answer (score 4):

Looking at [the python docs](https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/inputoutput.html), you can find multiple ways.

```
firstnoun = input("Enter your first noun here:")

print("The " + firstnoun + " went to the lake")
print("The %s went to the lake" % firstnoun)
print("The {} went to the lake".format(firstnoun))
```

or even using `format` with keywords

```
    print("The {noun} went to the lake".format(noun=firstnoun))
```

Comment: Nice to show 3 ways.  The string concatenation may be slower, at least if you do a lot of it.

Comment: Yeah, string concatenation is my least favorite way since you easily run into problems like trying to concat non-strings like numbers whereas string formatting works with those values also nicely.

Comment: Since Python 3.6, you can also use f-strings (my absolute favorite!):

`print(f'The {firstnoun} went to the lake")`

Answer (score 1):

Use string concatenation to build the output you wish:

```
print("The " + firstnoun + " went to the lake.")
```

For more advanced formatting, use `format()`:

```
print("The {0} went to the lake.".format(firstnoun))
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to *interpolate* the value.

Here's a general example to show the concept which you can then apply to your homework:

x = "foo"

`print("The word is {0}".format(x))`

Also, no, a `main` function is not necessary.