# How to stack print and input on the same line

Tags: python, input, printing

So what i wanna do is simply that
Example:

```
Print ('6 is between:') , p=int(input()),print('and:'), g=int(input())
```

The final will be
-6 is between (input) and (input)
Any suggestions pls

Comment: ``print('6 is between:', input(), 'and:', input())`` - unless you need the variables later, in which case you should gather all your inputs first and then use the variables in the print statement.

Comment: Search for how to format strings in Python.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do I get a user inputted variable into a sentence?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26006852/how-do-i-get-a-user-inputted-variable-into-a-sentence)

Answer (score 0):

You can even set the number and check if the statement is true with this code!

```
num = 6
a = int(input())
b = int(input())

print(str(num) + ' is between ' + str(a) + ' and ' + str(b))

print((a <= num) and (b >= num)) # Check if the input is True or False
```

Comment: "*The final will be -6 is between (input) and (input)*" OP wants it all in one line.