# Running input through linux command with python

Tags: python, linux

I'm new to python networking. I need to run a Linux command to capture traffic, but I need a mac-address input.

I've tried using pythons to do it, but I don't know how to import value get from the user to my command

```
#!/usr/bin/python
import os
mac-addr = input("Enter MAC-address"\n)
cmd = 'tcpdump -ni eth1 ether **<MAC-address need to be here>** -c 100 -w /opt/mirror-traffic/mirror_$(%A-%B-%d-%Y_%H-%M-%S).pcap'
output = os.system(cmd)
```

Comment: Read a tutorial on string manipulation?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do I get a user inputted variable into a sentence?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26006852/how-do-i-get-a-user-inputted-variable-into-a-sentence)

Comment: I don't want to print "input", I just want to take input to run the cmd.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. https://www.w3schools.com/python/ref_string_format.asp
2. you can't name variable mac-addr
3. input("Enter MAC-address\n")